# How to Replace ODBC Data Source with OLE DB Data Source in SSIS Package?

Tags: etl, business-intelligence, ssis, ssis-2012

I use Integration Services 2012 in project deployment mode. I want to replace existing ODBC data source with OLE DB data source in existing package without breaking all the links that cascade down the package into the data destination.

I have tried deleting the ODBC & adding OLE DB data source. Then I lost all my output aliases after the first MERGE JOIN data flow. What can I do about it?

Comment: First fix all of the metadata in your source components, by opening them for edit.  Then edit each component in order in the data flow.  This will often fix downstream components as you go, but if data types changed (i.e. unicode to non-unicode) then you may have conversions to do.

Comment: @Mark, please post it as the answer. The issue is that data types changed from numeric to decimal when I swapped odbc with ole db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First fix all of the metadata in your source components, by opening them for edit. Then edit each component in order in the data flow. This will often fix downstream components as you go, but if data types changed (i.e. unicode to non-unicode) then you may have conversions to do.